# SVG Ionic Angular and external script

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, ionic2, electron

My goal is to retrieve a click on a `svg`.

`svg` is a file with some `<rect />` that contains data to navigate inside the `app`, (`app` that is wrapped in `electron` module).

So, I found a good tutorial for call external javascript from `svg` by this way

Inside `svg`

```
    document.getElementById("svgroot").addEventListener("click", sendClickToParentDocument, false);

    function sendClickToParentDocument(evt)
    {
        // SVGElementInstance objects aren't normal DOM nodes, so fetch the corresponding 'use' element instead
        var target = evt.target;
        if(target.correspondingUseElement)
            target = target.correspondingUseElement;

  // call a method in the parent document if it exists
  if (window.parent.svgElementClicked)
            window.parent.svgElementClicked(target);
        else
            alert("You clicked '" + target.id + "' which is a " + target.nodeName + " element");
    }
```

In `index.html`

```
function svgElementClicked(target)
{
    var s = document.getElementById("status");
    s.textContent = "A <" + target.nodeName + 
    "> element with id '" + target.id + 
    "' was clicked inside the <" + 
    target.ownerDocument.defaultView.frameElement.nodeName.toLowerCase() + 
    "> element.";
}
```

Working well, but i'm with `Ionic` and `electron`, and I need to retrieve the target inside `app`.

I tried to move the external function in main.ts or any .ts, but I got the alert (`window.parent.svgElementClicked` is probably null).

I tried to pass a global variable, but same issue, the variable is never filled in `app`.

So, how I can resolve this problem ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work with angular.

you have to edit your svg rects as follow :

define onClick() in your component.
onClick will emit an event. this implies to define an Ouput EventEmitter;

some reading : https://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Can you be more precise? I can without problem inject a (click) in <rect /> when the svg is inline, but the issue is coming when the svg is loaded as object. Then all `angular` stuff is broken. Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more precise? I can without problem inject a (click) in <rect /> when the svg is inline, but the issue is coming when the svg is loaded as object. Then all `angular` stuff is broken. Thank you.

Comment: I mean your svg file must be an angular component. accessing and using directly the dom, like you did will not work well . in this case, bad behaviours will occur.
1/ create  mysvgcomponent
2/ copy your svg file content in mysvgcomponent.component.html 
3/ define your logic in the application/and the component